# Python Keyboard Module Select

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, module

Simply asked, will the `keyboard.is_pressed()` function work if I don't have the shell selected? So if I open notepad and then press the selected key, will it still run my code or do I have to have the shell open and selected? Windows 10 question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you saying when first running the script after that minimizing shell and opening the notepad for other work then when you press the selected key then keyboard.is_pressed() function works? yes it works no matter which applications are open or selected.

Comment: yes that is what im asking. I would test this myself on any other day but my laptop is having work done and im stuck on this stupid chromebook. lol as far as I know most online python testers dont support this modules.